# How to use instance class in C# console app

Tags: c#, class, console-application, instance

Trying understand c# console app, static make me crazy.

In my app:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {TimerCallback callback...}
static void Tick(Object state) { !here the problem! }
class myclass { all app logic }
```

Problem is, in Tick method i need use instance of myclass, but i cant create new instance like:

```
 myclass mc = new myclass();
 static void Tick(){}...
```

"An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". It works if i put myclass inside of Tick, but timer will be always create new instance of myclass, and all data in the class will dissapear.

P.S. sorry my english.

Comment: Edit your question to include code that compiles.

Comment: Can you post a more detailed sample of the code you are trying to execute?  Since the code you have written doesn't compile it is quite hard to work out what you are trying to do.

Comment: Did you put your class public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want something like this:

```
static MyClass myClass;
static void Main(string[] args) { myClass = new MyClass(); TimerCallback callback... }
static void Tick(Object state) { myClass.DoSomething(); }
class MyClass { all app logic }
```

That is, create a static field that will contain an instance of `MyClass`, and use that in your static methods.